# MyPointcutAdvisor (extends AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor) and MyInterceptor (implements MethodInterceptor) are not called

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-aop

**What I am trying to achieve**:
I am using Spring MVC. I need to intercept `Controller` methods that have `RequestMapping` annotation in an proper AOP way. Basically, when the server starts up, Spring should register my advisor bean and my interceptor bean and establish the AOP connection.

**Restrictions:**
I am **not** allowed to use AspectJ **at all** (Or I won't be posting this question).

**What I have so far**:
MyPointcutAdvisor calss:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyPointcutAdvisor extends AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor {

@Override
public Pointcut getPointcut() {
    return new Pointcut() {
        public MethodMatcher getMethodMatcher() {
            return new MethodMatcher() {
                public boolean matches(Method method, Class<?> targetClass, Object[] args) {
                    return matches(method, targetClass);
                }
                public boolean matches(Method method, Class<?> targetClass) {
                    return (method.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class) != null) ? true : false;
                }
                public boolean isRuntime() {
                    return true;
                }
            };
        }
        public ClassFilter getClassFilter() {
            return new ClassFilter() {
                public boolean matches(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return (clazz.getAnnotation(Controller.class) != null) ? true : false;
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

MyInterceptor class:

```
public class MyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

@Override
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Method intercepted!);
    return invocation.proceed();
}
```

In dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean class="package.MyPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="adviceBeanName" value="package.MyInterceptor"/>
</bean>
<bean class="package.MyInterceptor"/>
```

**Result so far**:

Server starts up without any exception but the advice/interceptor is not working (Nothing is printed out).

By setting break points, I can see the `MyInterceptor` is injected by spring through `setAdviceBeanName(String adviceBeanName)` in `AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor` class, however, the advice is never executed.

It seems to me like Spring is not aware of the advice at all. The pointcut is never retrieved either (IDE doesn't break on `getPointcut()` method).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to ensure you have an auto-proxy creator registered to the context. You can do this by programmatically registering your bean using a [`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html).

```
public class MyBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

        private static final String MY_ADVISOR_BEAN_NAME = "package.MyAdvisor";

        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
            // Do nothing.
        }

        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
            // Ensure an auto-proxy creator is registered.
            AopConfigUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(registry);

            RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition(MyPointcutAdvisor.class);
            // Bean will only be auto-proxied if it has infrastructure role.
            beanDefinition.setRole(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE);
            registry.registerBeanDefinition(MY_ADVISOR_BEAN_NAME, beanDefinition);
        }
}
```

This is essentially how the Spring Transaction library registers its advice to intercept `@Transactional` classes and methods when enabled via `<tx:annotation-driven/>`.

Using this method, if you wish, you can simply use [`PointcutAdvisor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/aop/PointcutAdvisor.html) instead of `AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor`.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is incorrect

```
<bean class="package.MyPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="adviceBeanName" value="package.MyInterceptor"/>
</bean>
```

The `value` attribute for the `name` property should have the name of the bean that is a `MethodInterceptor`.

Your bean doesn't have a name (or rather it has a default one). Add one explicitly

```
<bean name="interceptor" class="package.MyInterceptor"/>
```

then refer to it

```
<bean class="package.MyPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="adviceBeanName" value="interceptor"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I should have added name for the beans. However, this is not the reason behind the curtain. Advice is still not executed.

Comment: @Conan It works for me. Can you add more details? Post your full servlet context.

Comment: I believe the real reason was there is a proxy missing. @Brendan's method solved the problem.

Comment: @Conan What kind of `ApplicationContext` are you using?

Comment: sorry I am not following, what kind of `ApplicationContext`? XML?

Comment: @Conan Your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` is loaded by an `ApplicationContext` implementation. Most likely `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext`. If your were using Java configuration instead of XML with `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`, you could annotate your `@Configuration` class with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to do what Brendan suggested automatically.

Comment: What you said is definately correct. AspectJ would solve the problem way easier (And it worked, that was my first solution). However, as I wrote in the description, due to restrictions (which we don't like), AspectJ is **totally** forbidden in my situation.

Comment: @Conan That annotation simply sets up the appropriate factories, it doesn't use anything from aspectj.